# Open another Childform over currrent child form in tabpage of form1 Dont want to close or hide previous form in tab

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

i have single tab page in form1 and a button is placed inside tab to open a childForm(Form2).... Form2 loads pefectly in tabpage1 on buttonclick ..... and now on ChildForm(Form2) i have another button to call For ChildForm(Form3) ...but somehow it doesn't Load..nor throw some error ....well here is my Code

```
    public Form1//
    private void LoadForm(object Form)
    {
        Form childForm = Form as Form;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        int curr = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
        TabPage tbp = tabControl1.TabPages[curr];
        tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(tbp);
        tbp.Controls.Add(childForm);
        childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        childForm.Show();
        Refresh();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadForm(new Form2());
    }     
    public void OpenForm();
    {
        LoadForm(new Form3());
    }
   Form2//
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.OpenForm(new Form3());
    }
```

}enter image description here
}

Comment: The new form is underneath the old one.  Delete the Contains() call, replace it with while (tbp.Controls.Count > 0) tbp.Controls[0].Dispose();

Comment: thanks Bro Solved my problem by Adding .BringtoFront to my form ....thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Form1//
private void LoadForm(object Form)
{
    Form childForm = Form as Form;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    int curr = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;
    TabPage tbp = tabControl1.TabPages[curr];
    tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(tbp);
    tbp.Controls.Add(childForm);
    childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    childForm.Show();
    childForm.BringToFront();
    Refresh();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadForm(new Form2());
}     
public void OpenForm();
{
    LoadForm(new Form3());
}
Form2//
static Form1 f1;
Public Form2( Form1 refer)
{   InitializeComponent();
    f1 = refer;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   f1.LoadForm();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).